# Difference in definition of differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Okay so quite often I see two different definitions of differentiation and I want to know when it is appropriate to use each one.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

Why are their to definitions, how are they different and when do you use each one ?

Comment: By experience one chooses either one for convenience.

Comment: $x - x_{0} = h$..

Comment: ......$h=x-x_0$

Answer (score 1):

It is almost routine in mathematics than one thing can be expressed into two different visible forms without any problem and in most cases it is a matter of convenience to prefer one form over another. For example we can write $1/2$ as $0.5$ also and it does not matter which form we choose.

In a similar manner both the definitions of derivative are equivalent. It should be easy to prove that $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}g(a + h)$ and choosing $a = x_{0}$ and $g(x) = \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}}$ we see that $$\lim_{x \to x_{0}}g(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}g(x_{0} + h)$$ or $$\lim_{x \to x_{0}}\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})}{h}$$

Answer (score -1):

This is essentially the mean value theorem.
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

Note how similar this formula is to calculating the slope of a line.

$$m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

Also note that $x-x_0$ is essentially the h in the definition of the derivative, as $\lim_{x\to x_0} x-x_0$ goes to zero, just as h does. The mean value theorem can be derived by approximating f'(x) with secant lines. Let $x$ go to $x_0$ and it will yield tangent lines. However, both should yield the same answer. They are two ways of expressing the same idea. I would recognize the first one as the true definition of a derivative, but the mean value theorem is also useful for differentiation.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with the MVT.

Comment: @zhw. Explain. Aside from the limit as one point approaches another, the formulas are nearly identical.

Comment: For one thing, the MVT assumes differentiability on an interval, and we're talking here about a derivative at just one point. The MVT is not derived by approximating anything w secant lines. It follows from Rolle, which follows from the existence of a maximum/minimum value of a continuous function on a closed bounded interval. The equivalence of the "two" ways of writing the derivative at a point is just something you have to muck through at the beginning.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Mvt.

Comment: @zhw. You misunderstand. My intent is to convey the idea of this "alternative" definition of the derivative by approaching it from the perspective of MVT. MVT is useful for finding lines that are tangent on an interval, yes, but if you let one point approach another, the limit of that *is* the formula shown above. I remember this approach since first semester of Cal and it made so much sense to me. The professor demonstrated that the secant line method of deriving the definition of a derivative is useful thus, I thought it could be of value. It is not my intention to contradict existing maths.